What verb is this? ひっ倒し. Trying to make sense of this sequence of events
彼は瓶を掲げ、頬いっぱいにビールを溜め込む。
そうして、勢いよく飛びかかってきた。
肩を掴まれ、押し倒される————
が、その勢いを流して巴投げをする。
彼は口から霧状のビールを吐いた。
自分を真横にひっ倒し、彼は楽しそうに息を荒げる。
The sequence involve a drunk person "coming at the main character and I guess trying to tackle him. The main character dodges the issue and perform a judo technique on him which results in the guy puking. .(I'm a bit puzzled by 勢いを流して, as far I can see it means like making use of the flow or something?)
Then it adds:
自分を真横にひっ倒し、彼は楽しそうに息を荒げる。
I'm very puzzles, what exactly is going on in the first part of this sentence? Some google search seem to use を真横に akin to "At my side" but I can't make sense of ひっ倒し here. It's not a proper verb as far I can see.

https://jisho.org/word/引っ

Ya, as @Arfrever mentions, I suspect this is an alternative / contracted / shifted pronunciation of 引き【ひき】倒し【たおし】.

As pointed out in the comment section, ひっ is a prefix derived from 引く. It sometimes has a physical meaning of "pulling", but it sometimes adds a sense of forceful action, and in some cases forms a compound verb with a different meaning.

捕らえる (to capture) / ひっ捕らえる (to arrest violently)
はたく (to slap) / ひっぱたく (to slap hard)
掻く (to scratch) / 引っ掻く (to scratch hard; to claw at)
越す (to cross) / 引っ越す (to move house)
張る (to stretch) / 引っ張る (to pull)

ひっ倒す is not a very common combination, but you can understand it as a forceful version of 倒す, and it does not necessarily carry a meaning of pulling. (引き倒す on the other hand definitely has the meaning of pulling.)
Nevertheless, it's indeed difficult to understand what's happening here. Since the main character just performed 巴投げ, he is already lying down, so it seems impossible to knock him down further from that position. It may be best to dismiss this as a poorly written sentence.
勢いを流す means "to deflect/redirect the momentum (of the opponent)".
